# R predict function returning NULL value

Tags: r, null, statistics, classification

So I'm trying to use linear discriminant analysis to obtain the confusion matrix but my predict function keeps on having value 'NULL' in the Environment.

My code is

```
library(ISLR)
library(MASS)
data(Default)

set.seed(42); TrData = sample(nrow(Default), nrow(Default)*0.5)
TrSet = Default[TrData,]
fit= lda(default ~ income+balance, data=TrSet)

fit.p = predict(fit,newdata=TrSet[,-c(1)])$default
```

fit.p has value NULL so I cannot then obtain the confusion matrix
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: sorry I have now changed it

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: after your update you change `$Class` to `$default`. You still should use `$class`.

So you subset `$Class` instead of `$class`, as a non-existing filed from list or env gives you NULL.

```
ee <- new.env()
ll <- list()
ee[["WRONG"]]
# NULL
ll[["WRONG"]]
# NULL
```

From `MASS::lda` examples, last line is `$class` NOT `$Class`:

```
library(ISLR)
library(MASS)
data(Default)
set.seed(42)
TrData = sample(nrow(Default), nrow(Default) * 0.5)
TrSet = Default[TrData, ]
fit= lda(default ~ income + balance, data = TrSet)

fit.p = predict(fit,newdata = TrSet)$class
```

In your example please update the last line to
`fit.p = predict(...)$class`

Comment: Also the `[, -c(1)]` is not needed.

Comment: It is not the source of the problem, but agree it could be simplified. I think first of all prediction should be done on test not train set;p